# how do I fix HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, wordpress, http, html, http-status-code-500

I'm basically building a website with Wordpress and when I swapped the theme for the first time, it didn't let me do the change of theme. Then a bit later, I straight up couldn't view the website or the Wordpress page. Did I do something wrong? The link to the website is here: http://iwear.pk

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do I do this from the cPanel

Comment: Cpanel does have an "Error" logs section.

Comment: It just shows a box with nothing inside it. It might be because no error was detected.

Comment: I'm like an idiot at web design, I'm using wordpress. So I don't get what the best answer on that page is saying. I mean I'm looking for the logs thing. And I checked the cPanel error logs which claims there aren't any errors. And all the code for the website is on the wordpress/ server so what should I do?

Comment: Try renaming (not deleting) your .htaccess file. It could be misconfigured.

Comment: I figured out how to show the error. Now I need to fix the code. Thanks